# Angular 1 Component router redirect from OnActivate lifecyle hook

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have a small problem with component router for angular 1. When I'm trying to redirect/ navigate to another component from $routerOnActivate lifecyle hook, I'm getting into an infinite loop of redirects from current component to desired component. In the best case scenario is not infinite, but it will redirect between those two paths multiple times. What I am trying to do is that if something goes wrong,`enter code here` I want to go my home page. So basically I'm trying to do something like:

```
this.$routerOnActivate = () => {
      this.$router.navigate(["abcd"]
}
```

If i'm wrapping the navigate action into a setTimeout with 100 delay for example,it works fine, but for my scenario this is not a good idea cause the app is really lazy on edge or IE and there, 100 miliseconds will be not enough.

Can you help me please with an idea?

Answer (score 0):

$timeout is the only way I have found to do this so far.

```
this.$routerOnActivate = () => {
  $timeout(this.$router.navigate.bind(this.$router, ["abcd"]))
  return $q.reject() // stops the current route
}
```